# Has anyone ever used a graph like this with Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, graph

I want to visualize a data using graph, this is the sample graph that i want to use it.

[image: graph]

I think the picture above is like time series graph types, data on the graph shows a random numbers in variety of time. If every data number is null or empty the graph is painting a full vertical red line.

My goal is to visualize a data like picture above, i already tried to use a different reactjs chart to visualize a data but can't 
make if every data number is null or empty the graph is painting a full vertical red line like the picture.

Has anyone ever used a chart like the picture above?

Comment: Please include what you have attempted in the question

Comment: Why are you looking for Reactjs charts when you can draw charts of your own. Use `d3.js` to draw this using `Bar chart`.

Comment: Will this work for you http://recharts.org/en-US/api/ComposedChart ? Recharts are build on top of D3

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, i will try to use recharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better if you try [Recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US/). It is a compo-sable charting library for react components.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, i will try to use recharts.